# Most recent way of getting youtube video direct link

Tags: video, hyperlink, youtube, download

I did some google on getting youtube direct video(like what keepvid did), and it seems that this way gives a response(as a HTML):
    http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={v_part}
BUT, the signature from that HTML is somehow wrong(compared to the one that keepvid get).

SO, how do you find that signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a JavaScript bookmarklet to that effect

[`svnpenn.github.io/bm`](http://svnpenn.github.io/bm)

Comment: THank for the link. I'll look into the code and try to see what you have done. P/S it confuses me at first on how to use it though

Comment: So what you did is parsing the flash_vars, then the url_fmt*... Got it. Thank. Will try to implement it but not in javascript